# KDB concatenating strings inside select/exec statements

Tags: string, kdb

I have a table T with column `` Sym:`IBM`MSFT`GOOG... ``  Want the easiest way to create new column of the form newColumn: "IBM_Buy","MSFT_Buy","GOOG_Buy",...

The following does NOT seem to do the trick:
`select ((string Sym),"_Buy") from T`

Comment: ,"_Buy" doesn't work because you're working with a vector in the select statement, not an "atom" (although in this case we're working with strings which are not atoms either!). So user1895961 answer is the correct way

Answer (score 9):

You need to use each-left (\:). Think of it as concatenating "_Buy" to each item on a list.

```
select (string[Sym],\:"_Buy") from T
```

Comment: + cast back to a symbol with `$

Comment: @user2393012 I thought that, but in his example the new col is populated with strings.

Answer (score 1):

```
t:([]sym:`IBM`MSFT`GOOG)

update newsym:(string sym) cross enlist "_Buy" from t
```

or **easy way (Dictionary Format)**

```
t[`newsym] :
(string t[`sym]) cross enlist "_Buy"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use `each-both (')` function with anonymous function in select statement:

`select {x, "_Buy"}'[Sym] from T`